# SIP authentication without cleartext password

Tags: authentication, sip, digest-authentication

I have a client that initiates calls through a proxy that requires authentication.

The proxy sends a challenge to the client and the client responds with the credentials.

Is it possible to respond to the challenge without the password in cleartext?

The point is that I don't think storing the password in cleartext on the client is a good idea, especially in this case, since anyone that knows the password would be able to make calls using the account of another person.

I know that storing the hash of a password is okay on the authenticating side (the proxy in this example), but I never saw such thing on client side.

Thanks, Mickael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it won't be in clear text because the challenge will state MD5, e.g. (from RFC 3261):

> Proxy-Authenticate: Digest realm="atlanta.com",
>         domain="sip:ss1.carrier.com", qop="auth",
>         nonce="f84f1cec41e6cbe5aea9c8e88d359",
>         opaque="", stale=FALSE, algorithm=MD5

If it doesn't say MD5, that's an issue with your proxy.

If you know the realm, you can store the first stage of the response with password as an MD5 hash, along with the username (use of nonce comes later). Otherwise you'd have to use a reversible form of encryption locally for it.

Comment: Thank you! If I understand well, assuming the realm is known, you meant saving the hash of the "username:realm:password" (i.e. A1)? So, the idea would be to save one hash per algorithm that may be used, and the password can be kept safely on the client.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant and would keep the password secure enough. However I don't see Realm used so much in client side configuration, so really depends on your target system if that's reasonable. Not sure about other algorithms, I've only ever seen MD5.